# Change line spacing in JTextArea (not JTextPane)

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtextarea, css

I'm trying to find a way to change the line spacing in a JTextArea component.

A little bit of searching always seems to reveal the same answer: "Use a JTextPane instead and then call setParagraphAttributes".

But I'm wondering whether it's possible to achieve this with just a JTextArea by, for example, messing with the font.

With the `deriveFont(...)` method, it's possible to change the tracking and the kerning of the font, i.e. the horizontal spacing between characters, but I haven't been able to find a way to change the vertical spacing (maybe ascent, descent, leading). Am I missing something there?

Comment: you need to 1. add all methods from JTextPane to your own JTextArea, 2. to use Html and required another tricks to force rendering Html in JTextArea correctly

Comment: `A little bit of searching always seems to reveal the same answer:` - so what is wrong with a JTextPane? Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel for a JTextArea?

Comment: :) I expected these comments... Sometimes I'm simply interested in learning something new and figuring out what's possible. There's a billion options for this `deriveFont(...)` function, including applying matrix-based geometric transformations, etc. I'm just wondering if it's possible to do some magic with that. It's pretty poorly documented, so some use-case examples would be nice. BTW: What's wrong with light-weight coding? Why go to a full rich-text JTextPane if a simple JTextArea can do the trick?

Comment: No other ideas, anyone??? ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As camickr pointed out, `JTextArea` does not provide a way to change the line height directly. It simply uses the font height provided by the corresponding `FontMetrics`.

But, this leaves a point of attack open using the following helper-class:

```
public class FontMetricsWrapper extends FontMetrics {

    private final FontMetrics target;

    public FontMetricsWrapper(FontMetrics target) {
        super(target.getFont());
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override
    public int bytesWidth(byte[] data, int off, int len) {
        return target.bytesWidth(data, off, len);
    }

    @Override
    public int charWidth(char ch) {
        return target.charWidth(ch);
    }

    @Override
    public int charWidth(int codePoint) {
        return target.charWidth(codePoint);
    }

    // ... tons more @Override's, all of the same form:
    //
    // @Override
    // public baz foo(bar, ...) {
    //     return target.foo(bar, ...);
    // }

}
```

Then, it becomes possible to create the JTextArea like this:

```
JTextArea myTextArea = new JTextArea("Some text") {
    @Override
    public FontMetrics getFontMetrics(Font font) {
        return new FontMetricsWrapper(super.getFontMetrics(font)) {
            @Override
            public int getHeight() {
                return 10;  // Gives line height in pixels
            }
        };
    }
};
```

This is definitely not the cleanest solution and is merely meant as proof of concept. For example, one issue is that `getFontMetrics(...)` is called quite often, and, in the given example, creates a new instance of the wrapper class each time. So, at the very least, a HashMap that caches the created `FontMetricsWrapper` for each given font would be in order...

But, what I was really hoping for was a way to play with the `Font` or maybe the associated `FontRenderContext` passed into the JTextArea to modify the line height. For example, is there some way to influence font's reported ascent, descent, and leading values? Seems strange that you can change pretty much any other aspect of the font's appearance, except this one...

Answer (score 2):

> What's wrong with light-weight coding?

Nothing, you should use the simplest component for the job. But if the simple component doesn't support a requirement it is usually because the requirement is more complex and you need a more complex component to implement the functionality. Rarely would it be as simple at setting a property of a class.

> Sometimes I'm simply interested in learning something new and figuring out what's possible.

Swing text components use a `View` to paint the text. It is the view's responsibility to format and position the text. So each view determines when to wrap and where to position the next line.

In the case of a JTextArea it uses either a Plainview or a WrappedPlanView. For the Plainview the painting code is:

```
drawLine(line, g, x, y);
y += fontHeight;
```

where the fontHeight is determined by using the FontMetrics.getHeight() method.

So the value is basically hard coded in the View. You could always provide a custom View for your text area, but overriding a View is generally not an easy task.

Comment: Correct... That's why I was hoping for a way to maybe mess with the font given to the JTextArea instead of the text area. I found one way to do this (see my answer), but one can probably do better.

Comment: BTW: This little adventure is teaching me quite a lot about Swing. I'm somewhat new to Swing and had no idea how complex it is under the hood. Can be fun to open Pandora's box sometimes and actually dive into all the springs and gears that make everything work. Even if I never actually should/need to mess with any of it, I still like learning about the concepts (here: Components, UIs, RenderContexts, Views, Metrics, ...). Often there are some clever ideas to be found about how to structure code and solve certain issues elegantly, although, in this case, it looks like a bit of a mess... ;)